# How to drag a UserControl into the Toolbox?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, user-controls, webusercontrols

i have an ASP.net `UserControl` that i want to *use*:

[image]

Following the instructions in Visual Studio:

> There are no usable controls in this group.
>   Drag an item onto this text to add it to the toolbox.

i try dragging the item onto that text to add it to the toolbox:

[image]

Unfortunately, dragging an item onto that text does not add it to the toolbox:

[image]

So that raises the question:

> How do i drag a UserControl into the Toolbox?

**Note**

- building, or rebuilding, does not automatically add the control to the toolbox
- the **Choose Items** dialog does not include user controls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. Just drag the UserControl from the solution explorer onto the design surface. No need to add it into the toolbox first.

[Here is a relevant article in the asp.net forum.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1285684.aspx/1?How%20to%20add%20ascx%20user%20control%20to%20design%20page%20)

Answer (score 2):

Is the following link of any help

http://dhavalupadhyaya.wordpress.com/2008/07/20/how-to-add-custom-control-in-visual-studio-toolbox/

Comment: Unfortunately not. That's for a control that resides in a separately compiled assembly (*.dll)

Comment: In that case, i dont think you will be able to drop and ascx file from the solution explorer to the toolbox. I think VS expects an assembly as a drop element and not an object of type 'ascx" as the drop element. If you dont mind, can i put forth a suggestion , please which i am sure you would know.. having the controls in a separate assembly is always a good idea.. :)

Comment: i've actually been doing a lot of work [to get rid of separate assemblies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262251/visual-studiosource-control-how-to-have-shared-code); [copying code out of separate assemblies into the native solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116465/how-do-you-share-code-between-projects-solutions-in-visual-studio). Makes things so much better.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** do with `UserControls`.
**But** using **`ASP.NET ServerControls`** you can achive it.
Go through this article.
http://devoptions.blogspot.com/2015/02/create-aspnet-server-controls-from.html