# How to put Web User Control in toolbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:WebUserControl1 runat=\"server\"></{0}:WebUserControl1>")]  
[ToolboxItem(true)]  
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

when I drag it out and drop to aspx nothing happen.
Of course i already convert it become custom control from here [Turning an ascx user control into a redistributable custom control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2005/10/31/turning-an-ascx-user-control-into-a-redistributable-custom-control.aspx)

Comment: Go to: Tools -> Options -> Windows Forms Designer and enable the "AutoToolboxPopulate" option.

Comment: @Rahul this is "Web User Control"

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't add ascx to Toolbox. If that was Windows forms application user control would show up there automatically. David's post is about compiling web user control as a separate dll ( which only applies if its a web site, not web application) and reusing it. Only option is you  make it a composite control to show up in Toolbox.

[How to drag a UserControl into the Toolbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658446/how-to-drag-a-usercontrol-into-the-toolbox)